# Cakephp find problem

Tags: cakephp

I want to query as below in cakePHP.so, How can I do query using 'find' function of cakePHP .
Help me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Property.City),'city' as Fieldname FROM `properties` as Property WHERE Property.City LIKE 'las%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$this->Property->find( 
  'all', 
  array( 
    'fields'     => array( 'DISTINCT ( Property.city )' ),
    'conditions' => array( 'Property.city LIKE' => 'las%' )
  )
```

I threw this up from memory, but it should be close. I'm also sure that `DISTINCT` queries are at least mentioned in the documentation. Probably in the "complex finds" section.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: I also want another field having 'city' as  value ..what about that sir?

Comment: I think this should work, however Cake sometimes chokes on the strangely named fields. If that happens, try `'fields' => array("DISTINCT(Property.city) as 'Property.city'")`

Comment: @jimit, why do you need that in your find query? Just add it afterwards?